# List<SdtBlock> use to print Table on content control

Tags: c#, datatable, ms-word, openxml

I am quite new to this, So i do not have much idea about it. I'm trying to print a table to a Content control from a Database (MSSQL), the webservice is supposed to fetch some records and put it to a content control in the form of a table using List.

So I do something like this

```
public bool PrintTableonContentControl(string connectionString, string DbQuery,string filePath, string placeholderText)
{
    try{

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)){
        con.Open();

    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(DbQuery,con)){
        using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)){
            da.Fill(dt);

        using(WordprocessingDocument theDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, true)){
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = theDoc.MainDocumentPart;
            List<SdtBlock> sdtSubTable = mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtBlock>().Where(r => r.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>().Val.Value.Contains(placeholderText)).ToList();

            // Here it should print the Table on the content control and save 

                }
            }
        }
    }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
         throw ex;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Normally, I know how to use the simple Text and have the text displayed on a Content control, but tables? I have not seen any useful documentation on that, Please I would be needing help in this case.

Comment: Looking at Cindy's link above, why did you ask the same question twice? Anyhow, my answer below tells you exactly what kind of markup you need to create within your content control / `w:sdtContent` / `SdtContentBlock`. You'll obviously need one `w:tr` (`TableRow`) for each row of your `DataTable`. And the number of `w:tc` elements (`TableCell` instances) within each `w:tr` depends on the number of columns in your data table rows.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to render a table (`w:tbl` element or `Table` instance, respectively) within the block-level structured document tag (`w:sdt` element or `SdtBlock` instance). So let's look at what a table looks like in the following simplified sample document, which contains one `w:sdt` with a tag value `myTagValue`. Within the `w:sdtContent` element (or `SdtContentBlock` instance, you will have to render that `w:tbl` element (or `Table` instance). In this example, the table has three rows (one header row, two data rows) and two columns.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:body>
    <w:sdt>
      <w:sdtPr>
        <w:tag w:val="myTagValue" />
      </w:sdtPr>
      <w:sdtContent>
        <w:tbl>
          <w:tblPr>
            <w:tblStyle w:val="TableGrid"/>
            <w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto"/>
            <w:tblLook w:val="04A0" w:firstRow="1" w:lastRow="0" w:firstColumn="1" w:lastColumn="0" w:noHBand="0" w:noVBand="1"/>
          </w:tblPr>
          <w:tblGrid>
            <w:gridCol w:w="4531"/>
            <w:gridCol w:w="4531"/>
          </w:tblGrid>
          <w:tr>
            <w:tc>
              <w:tcPr>
                <w:tcW w:w="4531" w:type="dxa"/>
              </w:tcPr>
              <w:p>
                <w:r>
                  <w:t>Column Header 1</w:t>
                </w:r>
              </w:p>
            </w:tc>
            <w:tc>
              <w:tcPr>
                <w:tcW w:w="4531" w:type="dxa"/>
              </w:tcPr>
              <w:p>
                <w:r>
                  <w:t>Column Header 2</w:t>
                </w:r>
              </w:p>
            </w:tc>
          </w:tr>
          <w:tr>
            <w:tc>
              <w:tcPr>
                <w:tcW w:w="4531" w:type="dxa"/>
              </w:tcPr>
              <w:p>
                <w:r>
                  <w:t>Data Value 1.1</w:t>
                </w:r>
              </w:p>
            </w:tc>
            <w:tc>
              <w:tcPr>
                <w:tcW w:w="4531" w:type="dxa"/>
              </w:tcPr>
              <w:p>
                <w:r>
                  <w:t>Data Value 1.2</w:t>
                </w:r>
              </w:p>
            </w:tc>
          </w:tr>
          <w:tr>
            <w:tc>
              <w:tcPr>
                <w:tcW w:w="4531" w:type="dxa"/>
              </w:tcPr>
              <w:p>
                <w:r>
                  <w:t>Data value 2.1</w:t>
                </w:r>
              </w:p>
            </w:tc>
            <w:tc>
              <w:tcPr>
                <w:tcW w:w="4531" w:type="dxa"/>
              </w:tcPr>
              <w:p>
                <w:r>
                  <w:t>Data value 2.1</w:t>
                </w:r>
              </w:p>
            </w:tc>
          </w:tr>
        </w:tbl>
        <w:p />
      </w:sdtContent>
    </w:sdt>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

I recommend you look at the markup created by Microsoft Word, e.g., using the Open XML Productivity Tool or the Open XML Package Editor for Modern Visual Studios (a Visual Studio extension). You can then use Microsoft Word to create the layout and formatting of your table, using an example, and then render the corresponding markup based on your actual data.

Note that the Open XML SDK simply allows you to create that markup, using strongly typed classes such as `Document`, `Body`, `SdtBlock`, `SdtContentBlock`, or `Table`. The Open XML Productivity Tool tells you exactly which classes are required to create certain markup.